# Deep Populate con Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy ante un issue que no sé cómo afrontar. Pretendo realizar una query desde mongoose utlizando `deep populate`.

Para ello tengo el siguiente esquema:

```
const GrantTypeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    pi_scopes: [{
        ref: "pi_scopes",
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }],
    scopes: [{
        ref: "scopes",
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }],
    purposes: [{
        ref: "purposes",
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }]
}, { 
    _id: false, 
    versionKey: false 
});

const AppSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    redirect_uris: [String],
    legal_entity_id: String,
    requires_authoorization_id: Boolean,
    encrypt_access_tokens: Boolean,
    tags: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    description: String,
    http_callback: String,
    grant_types: [GrantTypeSchema],
    env: String,
    old: Schema.Types.Mixed,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
});
```

Querría poblar los distintos campos dentro de *GrantTypeSchema* (*pi_scopes*, *scopes* y *purposes*), os pongo un ejemplo de uno de estos esquemas:

```
const Title = new Schema({
    lang_id: String,
    value: String
}, { _id: false, versionKey: false, });

const Description = new Schema({
    lang_id: String,
    value: String
}, { _id: false, versionKey: false,  });


const PurposeSchema = new Schema({

    id: String,
    title: [Title],
    description: [Description],
    level: String,
    pi_scopes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "pi_scopes",
    }],
    purpose_type: String,
    env: String,
    old: Schema.Types.Mixed,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
});
```

El problema al que me enfrento es que *GrantType*, en *AppSchema*, es un Array de objetos, por lo tanto desconozco cómo puedo llegar a acceder a su interior (es decir, recorrer si se pudiese con un `for`, `foreach` o similares todos los contenidos de *grant_type* y aplicarles a todos los objetos el mismo `populate` de *scopes*, *piscopes* y *purposes*).

He estado leyendo acerca de `deep populate`, pero no he encontrado ninguna documentación o ejemplo donde me quede claro como debería realizar el proceso para obtener el resultado deseado.

Realmente lo que necesitaría obtener sería algo así como:

```
APP
|_data1
|
|_data2
|
|_datan
|
|_grant_types
       |
       |_grant_type1
       |       |
       |       |_scopes    >>>> populate
       |       |_pi_scopes >>>> populate
       |       |_purposes  >>>> pupulate
       |
       |_grant_typen
               |_scopes    >>>> populate
               |_pi_scopes >>>> populate
               |_purposes  >>>> populate
```

Personalmente creo que lo mejor sería tener algun tipo de forma de poder realizar un `for` en todos los elementos de *grant_types* ¿Sabéis si hay algún tipo de método que me ayude con este issue?

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo inconveniente si encontraste la solución a este problema seria bueno compartirla por este medio, muchos los agradeceríamos enormemente. Gracias.

Comment: Ya la tienes respondida, gracias por el PING, espero que sea de ayuda, un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que obtuve fue crear un populate que sea un array (para popular todos los campos que indicamos en este array), que se encuentre dentro de otro populate (el cual indica el path únicamente donde se encuentran), de esta forma conseguí obtener el resultado deseado.

Os pongo un ejemplo del código que me funciona a día de hoy:

```
try {
App.find(filter)
.populate({
path: 'grant_types',
populate: [
{ path: 'pi_scopes', model: Piscope },
{ path: 'scopes', model: Scope },
{ path: 'purposes', model: Purpose }
]
})
.exec( (e: any, d: any) => {
if(e) console.log(e);
})
} catch (e) {
console.log(e);
}
```

Leyendo la documentación he visto que esto mismo también se podría conseguir a través de la función aggregate, creando un pipeline dentro de esta.

Espero que os sea de ayuda.